# How to print input arguments in bash script as is

Tags: bash, quote

Could you please help, does exist a command in bash to quote input argument?

script `./test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo ${1}
```

`./test.sh "It costs $1"`
This prints `It costs`, but how to print it as is `It costs $1`.

Of course it is possible to quote the argument directly in the command:
`./test.sh "It costs \$1"`
and it prints `It costs $1`. But how to quote it in the script?

**UPDATED:** It is possible with single quotes `./test.sh 'It costs $1'`

Comment: Exactly as you just did: `echo "It costs \${1}"`, or with single quotes: `echo 'It costs ${1}'`.

Comment: When your script executes, it's already too late. There is nothing your script can do to get the original misquoted `$1`

Comment: Did you mean to print the an argument, or that the cost is a single dollar? `\$1` will do the latter. If you run as-is with just `./test.sh` you'll get what you're seeing, but try `./test.sh "a buck"`.   For real clarity, read [this manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/), especially [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameters.html#Shell-Parameters) & [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameters.html#Shell-Parameters).

Answer (score 2):

You may update your program like below to print/display all arguments.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "$@"
```

This will print all the arguments passed while running test.sh. $1 is a variable which substituted with empty string while calling your program `test.sh`. Inside test.sh, first argument you passed in command line becomes $1, second becomes $2 and so forth.

`$@` prints all arguments.

Comment: Indeed, it is useful to do `man bash` and read everything under `EXPANSION` heading. There is so much good info there that many people never see.

Answer (score 2):

I often use:

```
printf "'%s' "  "$@"
```

This is an alternative to echo when you want each argument quoted.